# get specific words from string , ORACLE

Tags: oracle, plsql

Kindly are there any one knows how to get a specific string from a huge string using pl/sql,
I'm some kind beginner in creating querys,so any help will be useful.
BTW i don't want to use the function : select substr( ***, * ,* ) from * cuz the input is variable, so can any one help me on this problem,
and do you advice me to use block instate of that.

Thanks & regards,

Comment: In PL/SQL you don't need to use a SELECT to use substr. You can just call it: v_result = substr(p_input, 1, 2);
Depending on what you are actually trying to achieve also have a look at [instr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm), [regexp_substr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions131.htm) and [regexp_instr](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/server.101/b10759/functions114.htm).

Comment: When asking questions like this you should give some sample inputs and some excetced outputs.  Help us to help you!

Comment: Are you after pl/sql or just sql? Some context would help you.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like you're looking for a specific string inside of a bigger string.  If so, the function you're probably looking for is INSTR:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm

Comment: Linking to Oracle documentation rather than third party would be better: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/olap.111/b28126/dml_functions_1103.htm

Answer (score 4):

As far my understanding to your question you want to `check` whether a `specific word` is present in a `string or not`  ,if this is the question you can find the solution below .

```
DECLARE
v_string VARCHAR2(200):='MY NAME IS GAURAV SONI';
v_check PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN

v_check:=INSTR(v_string,'GAURAV'); --this is case sensitive 

IF v_check >0 THEN 
dbms_output.put_line('Word exists');
END IF;

END;
```

In the above block we are searching Word `GAURAV` in the String `MY NAME IS GAURAV SONI` and this word exist in `12` place   .

Please note this is `Case sensitive` and if you put word `gaurav` ,value of `v_check` will be `zero`.

If you are are looking for `Case insensitive` then go for REGULAR EXPRESSIONS in oracle `REGEXP_INSTR` in place of `INSTR` .Read the oracle document before using this function [REGEXP_INSTR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions129.htm#i1239887)

[Worked out example in SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/245)